# Trying to uninstall rn-fetch-blob

Tags: react-native, yarnpkg

I am having issues uninstalling.

I have run rm -rf node_modules, yarn and react-native link, and then removed compile project(':rn-fetch-blob') from build.gradle, as other question suggested, but now I am getting more errors in the source code for Android when I try to run `react-native run-android` (probably will happen for iOS too).

```
> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
/.../MainApplication.java:6: error: package com.RNFetchBlob does not exist
import com.RNFetchBlob.RNFetchBlobPackage;
                      ^
/.../MainApplication.java:29: error: cannot find symbol
            new RNFetchBlobPackage(),
                ^
  symbol: class RNFetchBlobPackage
2 errors
```

I need help. This module feels like malware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best bet is to look at the manual installation steps for `rn-fetch-blob` and do the opposite of what they are saying

https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob/blob/master/README.md#user-content-installation

Manual installation instructions 
https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob/wiki/Manually-Link-Package#index

Comment: yeah i went as far as installing it back, doing `react-native unlink`, but still nothing.

Comment: You need to go through and manually remove all the things that it added. The manual installation instructions will show you what it added. You just do the opposite. Unlinking doesn’t really work.

Answer (score 0):

I exactly did the opposite of installation and it worked